# How to limit entries to aws javascript dynamodb per user?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Using the javascript web sdk that amazon just released, what is to prevent a user (even after federated auth) from abusing access to the database?

For example, how could you limit the length of a string that they can submit for a field?

Also, how could you limit the number of entries they submit for a table with multiple rows? Or on s3, limit the amount of files, or size of files, they can submit?

I can imagine how to control this in the node.js implementation, but it seems like someone could write their own script on the client side to circumvent rules.

EDIT: Just to clarify which SDK we are discussing: [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the only good answer to the question is very straightforward, even though you may not like it: "don't let them directly access the resource," followed closely by "trust no one."  The credentials for your services only belong in the hands of fully-trusted entities for whatever those credentials theoretically authorize, so I'm not sure who you're trying to protect against.

You limit the size of a field they can submit by validating their request to your application server and sending the request to the database or other underlying system -- or not -- depending on whether the request is valid.  Properly implemented at this point in your stack, such restrictions would be impossible to violate no matter what happened at the client side, and,conversely, any implementation that presumes the client side will behave correctly, predictably, reasonably, and as-intended is a very naive implementation, indeed.

Controlling such things is the job of the your application server, receiving client requests via *your* API -- the one that you design for your application to interact with clients -- validates them, and sends calls to the underlying systems to fulfill those requests that it deems legitimate.

Comment: This seems to defeat the purpose of the client side API that they released.  I want to believe that they planned for a way to control db  insertion size / counts as a way of making abuse inefficient.

Comment: I assumed the Javascript SDK was for Node on the *server* side.

Comment: The one they just released is for the client side.  Their Node version has been around for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IAM and provide specific permission for each user to access only his record.

For example, you can use DynamoDB fine-grained access control (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html), what when work together with web identity can provide access to records that start with his user-id. Read more here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/10/fine-grained-access-control-for-amazon-dynamodb.html

Comment: But suppose that you have an application and I sign up for it.  Now you only give me access to my record, but I'm malicious.  Now, I dump 10gigs of useless garbage to the db entry and you pay for it.  How does one prevent this?

Comment: Thanks Guy.  64GB is very high if someone wanted to be malicious.  I would think being able to limit a user to updating a max number of rows at a max filesize would be helpful. Eg: 100 rows, 100kb in size (or whatever makes sense for the app)

Comment: The auto correction is taking over... let's try again: 64 Kilo Byte not Giga Byte...